# Avoid displaying half UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

As shown in the image, my requirement is to avoid displaying half cell while scrolling....if i scroll more than half a height of cell and released, the cell should be completed scrolled to top..it is somewhat similar to setPagingEnabled concept...I want to implement same concept for each row.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
```

in UICollectionViewlayout. The return value is the offset you want to use instead of the one the user scrolled to. Assuming your row's height is `100` and the current `proposedContentOffset` is `(0,80)` then you would want to return `(0,100)` which would then scroll your collection view `20` more points. At that point, your previous row's cells won't be visible anymore.

Comment: thanQ for the reply..To implement your answer i have to reate another class which would be a child class of UICollectionViewFlowLayout....I found better answer as posted below. so that i can implement this method in the viewcontroller itself..

Answer (score 0):

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

  CGFloat proposedOffset = targetContentOffset->y;

  CGFloat heightOfPage =65;
  CGFloat heightOfSpacing = 5.0f;

  CGFloat numOfPage = lround(proposedOffset / (heightOfPage + heightOfSpacing));

  CGFloat newY = numOfPage * (heightOfPage + heightOfSpacing);

  // if the calculated y is bigger then the maximum possible y we adjust accordingly

  CGFloat contentHeight = _categoryCollectionView.contentSize.height;

  CGFloat collectionViewHeight = _categoryCollectionView.bounds.size.height;

  CGFloat maxY = contentHeight - collectionViewHeight;

  if (newY > maxY)

  {

  ```
  newY = maxY;
  ```

  }

  targetContentOffset->y = (newY);
  }